# powershell get Content - Autodesk Navisworks

Tags: powershell, autodesk, autodesk-navisworks

HI im trying to get the content of an Autodesk Navisworks (NWD) file.

here is a simple version of what im trying todo -

```
$fileCont = Get-Content -Path $filePath
New-Item C:\Temp\tom2.nwd
Set-Content C:\Temp\tom2.nwd $fileCont
```

For this to prove that I can successfully collect the content of the navisworks file..

although this is a simple workflow and what i'm trying to achieve is greater thank this, if i can figure this bit out i know the rest..

here is the error when i try to open `C:\Temp\tom2.nwd`

[image: Navisworks Error message when opening file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're correct this method did work but was extremely slow and un usable, but i can now confirm that by following [this post](https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell)

i used the following method to collect and post the data in the file.

```
  write-host "Creting object in bucket.."

$B_Key = ''
write-host "Bucket Key ="$B_Key

write-host "File Content being uploaded to bucket object"

$currentDir = Get-Location
$sourceFile = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($currentDir, 'rac_basic_sample_project_pstest.rvt')
$fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($SourceFile)
Set-ItemProperty -Path $sourceFile -Name IsReadOnly -Value $false

$Clen = Get-Item $sourceFile
$Clen = $Clen.Length
write-host $Clen

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
            $headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
            $headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
            $headers.Add("Content-Length", $CLen)

$CreateObj = 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/'+$B_Key+'/objects/'+$fileName 
$CreateObjAPIresult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $CreateObj -Method Put   -Headers $headers -InFile $sourceFile

write-host "New Object Created in bucket"
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, both [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) operate only on *text*.

**To handle raw *byte* data** - which is needed to handled the content of a *binary* file format such as `.nwd` - you need to use:

- in *Windows PowerShell*: `-Encoding Byte`
- in *PowerShell [Core] v6+*: `-AsByteStream`

Note: If all bytes fit into memory at once, you can greatly speed up a `Get-Content` call by adding `-Raw`.